# Защита от инъекций SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Мой код:

```
$content=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['cotent']);
else mysqli_query($CONNECT,
    "INSERT INTO news  VALUES ('', '$Info[id]', ".$content."', '', NOW(), '')");
```

В базу `content` записывается как пустое значение, но если делать вот так:

```
else mysqli_query($CONNECT,
    "INSERT INTO news  VALUES ('', '$Info[id]', '$_POST[cotent]', '', NOW(), '')");
```

то все работает. Подскажите, в чем я ошибся.

Comment: Вы пользуетесь устаревшей функцией `mysql_`, при том что для доступа к БД используете более новый mysqli. Не подставляйте _никакие_ переменные непосредственно в текст запроса. Используйте плейсхолдеры и привязку переменных http://php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: то есть то, что испльзуются разные библиотеки (mysql и mysqli) тебя не смущает? ну и собственно посмотри в документации как правильно  вызывается real_escape_string .....да и про подготовленные переменные ты как-то забыл

Comment: то эсть нужно использовать mysqli::real_escape_string но чтоо оно у меня не работает подскажите как его применить к моему коду

Comment: Ты забыл одну кавычку вокруг `$content` - одинарные кавычки должны быть с обоих сторон `'".$content."',`

Comment: Предлагаю для защиты от `SQL Injection` воспользоваться `PDO (PHP Data Object)`